# syntax error near unexpected token `(' comm -2 -3 <(sort PATH/FILE1) <(sort PATH/FILE2) > PATH/FILE3

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I am trying to compare file1 with file2 and redirect the difference to file 3 in Unix shell scripting.

I am getting below error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `(' 
comm -2 -3 <(sort PATH/FILE1)  <(sort PATH/FILE2) > PATH/FILE3
```

data in file1:

```
A
B
D
C
```

Data in file 2:

```
A
C
```

Output expected in file3:

```
B
D
```

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: i am using -bash

Comment: Can you prove it?

Comment: I fired this command:echo $0
-bash

Comment: And what is the command that gives you the error?

Comment: comm -2 -3 <(sort PATH/FILE1)  <(sort PATH/FILE2) > PATH/FILE3

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: You tagged your question `sh` (as well as bash) .  `echo $0` on the command-line will give `-bash`, but in a script should give the name of the script.  Just because your command-line is running `bash` it doesn't mean that your script is.  The syntax you show is valid in `bash` but not in `sh`.  So, are you running this in a script?  If so what `#!` line do you have, have you tried running it using `bash script-name`?  Alternatively, maybe you are running a very old version, so `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: One could get here if you were running bash in POSIX mode, but that's a thing that has to be explicitly turned on (and the answer is "don't do that").

Comment: Any chance the platform might be Cygwin? I recall there being Cygwin releases where process substitution didn't work right, despite the bash release itself having appropriate support.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `sort file` you get the sorted  output of that file, not a new file (name). But `comm` expects two files, not just file contents. You could either create temporary files,or try a different approach with `uniq`:

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq -u
```

First send both files' contents through `sort`, then the sorted contents get sent to `uniq`, which "reports or omits repeated lines". The `-u` tells it to print unique lines only.

Comment: True, but much less efficient than `comm`, which *is* the right tool for this job. See [BashFAQ #36](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036).

Comment: The OP's syntax error indicates that their shell isn't really bash -- if they ran `sh scriptname` or ran a script with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang, they would get exactly the behavior in their question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I get the same error on bash, without script and shebang line.

Comment: To be clear: `<(...)` expands to a new filename, which when read from contains the output of the code in `...`.

Comment: Fortunately, we can test this due to the availability of online interpreters. See https://ideone.com/rrydwR, working perfectly. Could you please post a similar link with a test case that fails?

Comment: ...you can also put the OP's original code into http://shellcheck.net/, and note that it parses there perfectly. I'm curious a to how you managed to get a failure -- maybe you changed the spacing? `<()` is a very specific construct -- you can't change it to `< ()`, for instance, and have it still work.

Comment: BTW, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst for guidance on the syntax in question, or the official bash manual's (terser) explanation at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html

Comment: BTW, **the output from this is explicitly different from the `comm` line that the OP provided.** Their original code emits only lines that exist in file1 but not file2; your code, unlike theirs, also includes lines present in file2 but not file1.